# In bash scripting, how can one check if a key is down?

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I just wrote a "on start up" script for Mac OS X and want it to NOT fire if I hold down a key, e.g. the shift key.

Anyone know how to check if the shift key is down from a bash script?

Comment: Before anything else, can you confirm that your script actually gets input? Because typically a startup script like that would not even seem the keyboard in the first place, so programming it to detect shift would be useless. Do an experiment and have it not start if it seem the a key or some other easy to read key.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6134/how-to-map-ctrl-shift-to-thumb-buttons-of-mouse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to interface with a Mac-OS-X-specific API that has this "hold down a key" concept. There's no such thing in bash, nor in related Unix/POSIX APIs. Doubly so with the modifier keys like Shift or Control.